# How to remove phantom changelist in Perforce

Tags: perforce

Yesterday one of our remote users was submitting a changelist through P4V. The submit appears to have succeeded - it shows up in the submitted tab, and I was able to sync the files from the changelist.

However, when I look at the files that were submitted in the depot view, it seems that the files are still marked for add/edit, and it lists the pending changelist with the number from when it was pending (prior to submission). But if I try to get the description of that changelist, I get a "no such changelist" message.

How can I remove this phantom changelist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, so you're saying that in one P4V you see the changelist (let's call it 100) as submitted, yet in another P4V you see it as still pending?  And when you try to run something like `p4 describe -s 100`, you get 'no such changelist'?

This is faintly ringing a bell, but the fastest way to figure out what's happening is to work with Perforce Support.  That's always my recommendation if you suspect there's any sort of data corruption going on.

Comment: Close, but not quite - it appears as submitted (with a new number) in all instances of P4V if you're looking in the submitted changelists tab. But if you're looking at the depot view, all instances of P4V will also show that the files from that changelist are marked for add/edit from the original changelist while it was pending. I'll contact support, it sounds like this is probably going to involve some surgery on the databases.

Comment: Could it be due to the 'reopen after submitting' preference?